# ExpiresIn vs maxAge

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am using the `jsonwebtoken` npm package for a project, and I came across   an `expiresIn` option when calling `jwt.sign(...)`. Another option is the `maxAge` of the `jwt.verify(...)` method.

What is the difference between the two ? Is one preferred over another ?

Answer (score 1):

`maxAge` is simply implemented as an additional way to limit the length of time a token is valid. This allows you to not accept a token even if it is not expired yet.

Generated jwts will include an `iat` (issued at) claim by default unless `noTimestamp` is specified. `maxAge` would use `iat` field to calculate the validation. On the other hand, `expiresIn` uses `exp` field.